# Can EGit (Eclipse git plugin) use an SSH key instead of a username and password?

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

The git central repository to which I need to commit is configured using SSH keys. My username is `jmglov`, but when I perform git operations (e.g. `git clone`), I use this configuration:

```
: jmglov@kitiara; cat .git/config 
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    url = git@git.example.com:AwesomeWare
```

When I try to use [EGit](http://www.eclipse.org/egit/) in [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) to push to the origin, I'm prompted for a password for the `git` user, for which only SSH keypair authentication is enabled. My public key is one of the authorised keys for the `git` user.

Is it possible to configure EGit to use my SSH key instead of the `git` user's credentials?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Yes, the configuration is picked up from the Eclipse preferences, as noted in the [EGit user guide](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Eclipse_SSH_Configuration)

[image: SSH preferences]

Comment: Perfect, thanks! One oddity that I noted is that I don't have the **Authentication Methods** tab. Any ideas why?

Comment: @Josh: not really. I just picked up the reference from the user guide. You might want to ask on the EGit mailing list.

Comment: and make sure you're on the latest version of EGit

Comment: This dialog has nothing to do with EGit, it's the standard Eclipse SSH preferences dialog.

Comment: Which version of Eclipse are you using?