# Egit for Eclipse on Mac OSX

Tags: eclipse, github, egit

I installed the Egit plugin for Eclipse on both of my Mac OSX and Windows. However they all have problem, but it seems Mac OSX is more serious when it comes to auth the key.

1. when i push the project to repository using the Team - Remote - Push, I tried many versions of the URL on the website, but all failed. I remembered it succeed once on Windows.
2. as another question "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601805/auth-problem-with-egit-and-github", i tried to load the private key to Eclipse, on Windows, after I clicked Load Existing Key, it prompt let me to enter pass, after that it works.

But i did the same way on Mac OSX, it doesn't work and it shows "failed to decrypt id_rsa". I don't know why. Because i used the same pass through ssh it works. How come???

1. after i create the repository and used ssh to connect and it works. Then i changed some files on Eclipse and commit, then Remote - Push, it prompt let me enter the pass, but still doesn't work on Mac OSX.(It works on Windows)

I am wondering who has experienced this kind of problems before? I just did that for fun, I don't use it for work. Anyone can tell me how do you fix that for work? using egit or ssh?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not clear on your question. Are you asking "How do I use ssh-key based authentication to authenticate my git connections through EGit?" The question you link to - ["Auth Failed" error with EGit and GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601805/auth-problem-with-egit-and-github) - seems to address a lot of problems you might have been having.

Eclipse needs to have the correct connection information. [Preferences => General => Network Connections => SSH2]. If this is correct, EGit should be able to use key-based authentication as answered here - [Can EGit (Eclipse git plugin) use an SSH key instead of a username and password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5935378/can-egit-eclipse-git-plugin-use-an-ssh-key-instead-of-a-username-and-password).

Also, if you haven't already found it, there is a pretty good user guide for EGit at http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide.

Answer (score 0):

Successfully solved issue:

It appears that the SSH key lengths are different when generated on the command line in OSX and when generated from Eclipse/EGit.

Similar posting here: [Eclipse Community Forums](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/200827/)

Observed that SSH keys generated from command line are 2048 in length, keys generated from within Eclipse/EGit are only 1024 in length.

Verify using: "ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your_email@youremail.com"  Key length is 2048

When Attempting to load an existing key from within "Preferences->General->NetworkConnections->SSH2" this fails with "failed to decrypt id_rsa"

When Generating a key from the same dialog; keylength is specified as RSA-1024

After following the directions at the link above, I got everything working again.  Note that the listing within Eclipse still shows length of 1024, but length of key reported by "ssh-add -l" still at 2048, same length as it was originally configured.